# Check asp.net mvc ValidationMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to check if ValidationMessage exists for a particular field in the model by using

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.amount).ToString())
```

but somehow its not working.
What is the best / accurate way to check if a validation has failed and if a validation message exists for that field.

What i am trying to do is to display normal helper message for input field but when validation  failes the helper message is to be replaced by validation message.

Comment: Why do you not just write up the logic for Html.ValidationMessageFor() in your view and have it behave normally?

Comment: @Maritim can you please provide a small example of your suggestion (with code)

Comment: To employ such a helper method you would have to write @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.amount) in your view, preferably on the line before or after where you render the form field itself. The framework usually takes care of the rest :)

Answer (score -1):

The below code snippet (MVC4) always works for me.

```
// in controller action. I think you might have missed this line 
ModelState.AddModelError("amount","Amount is invalid!");

// in view page
if (HtmlHelper.ValidationMessage("amount") != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HtmlHelper.ValidationMessage("amount").ToHtmlString()))
{
//field has error
}
```

Comment: Where's HtmlHelper defined??

Comment: it should be Html.ValidationMessage